# Powershell - Find and Replace and show work

Tags: powershell, replace, find

I have written this script to find "Procedure division" and replace it with a null value.  It seems to work, so that's a good this.

What I need to add is the actual file names that were changed.  I have 12K files and only around 800 or so are supposedly needing the change.  I need to know what ones were actually changed.
Is there a way to add the path and file name to be displayed in the below script?

```
$old = Read-Host 'PROCEDURE DIVISION.'
$new = Read-Host ''

Get-Children D:\temp *.cbl -recurse | ForEach {
   (Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace "$old", "$new"}) | Set-Content $_ 
}
```

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: Hi,The files are anywhere from 500 lines of code to 25K lines of code.

Comment: `$_.Name`, `_.FullName`.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your eartlier question? There, [I showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673602/9898643) how to output the path and filenames of the files that actually were updated..